# How to make a shared Github repo?

Tags: github, vercel

I'm making a project that I want to share with 3 other people, only I would be working on it. But I want to share the repo with them so they can host the project individually on Vercel by importing the repo from their Github accounts.

I know they can just fork it, but is it possible to link their "forked" repo to mine so when I make the changes it automatically changes their repo which should also automatically update the deployed project.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can invite users to become **collaborators** to your personal repository.

1. Ask for the username of the person you're inviting as a collaborator.
2. On GitHub.com, navigate to the main page of the repository.
3. Under your repository name, click  Settings.
4. In the "Access" section of the sidebar, click  **Collaborators & teams**.
5. Click Invite **a collaborator**.
6. In the search field, start typing the name of person you want to invite, then click a name in the list of matches.
7. Click **Add NAME to REPOSITORY**.
8. The user will receive an email inviting them to the repository. Once they accept your invitation, they will have collaborator access to your repository.

for more detail maybe you can check how to invite collaborators in **GitHub Documentation**.